Disable DHCP in Speedify connection sharing
I'm enabling speedify connection sharing by setting ENABLE_SHARE & SHARE_INTERFACE in /etc/speedify/speedify.conf, but I'm getting DHCP server on that interface after that.
I would like to use pihole as DNS & DHCP server but cannot find a way to disable DHCP on speedify.
